Oracle Automated Maintenance Tasks (autotask): client_name vs. operation?
What is the difference in purpose between Oracle's Automated Maintenance Tasks (autotask) client_name and operation?
I am aware that they can be identified with DBA_AUTOTASK_CLIENT and DBA_AUTOTASK_OPERATION views, respectively.
Neither Oracle 19 PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference – DBMS_AUTO_TASK_ADMIN nor Oracle 19 Database Administrator’s Guide - Managing Automated Database Maintenance Tasks explain the distinction.

This probably belongs on Database Administrators.
